# Add Field using loop (GIS Python)

Tags: python, loops, gis

The task at hand is:

Add 10 new fields to “SoilData” Attribute Table with the following specifications:

1. Names: “CODE1”, “CODE2”, …”CODE10”.
2. Use “AddFields_management()”method.
3. The fields are all “INTEGER”.
4. Use one loop (either “if””, “for”, or “while”) to add these 10 fields (no cursor required). The following shows the end product of the code.

My question is **how would this code look in a loop?**

My first attempt:

```
for fc in arcpy.SoilData():
  arcpy.AddField_management(in_table="Soil_Data", field_name="CODE", field_type="INTEGER")
  fieldName = {CODE [1:10]}
```

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: for fc in arcpy.SoilData():

                                                                                            arcpy.AddField_management(in_table="Soil_Data", field_name="CODE", \
                                                                                        field_type="INTEGER")
  
                                                                                        fieldName = {CODE [1:10]}

Comment: for fc in arcpy.SoilData():

  arcpy.AddField_management(in_table="Soil_Data", field_name="CODE", \
   field_type="INTEGER")

   fieldName = {CODE [1:10]}

Answer (score 0):

I don’t know for sure what’s the usage of “fc” in your code.I hope the following code will help.

```
n = range(1,11)
while n ! = [] :
    arcpy.AddField_management(“Soil_Data”,”COD”+str(n[0]),"INTEGER")
    remove(n[0])
```